# Android/ Java: trim cut the latitude for map view

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I have stored the latitude and longitude inside my database as a string, e.g 23.563987,120.761719

How can i trim them into two seperate integers so that it can fit into my code? thanks!

[and sorry that i'm new to java....]

My map code is as below:

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(23.563987,120.761719)).title("Marker"));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(
            23.563987,120.761719));
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

    mMap.moveCamera(center);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the strung and convert it back to doubles.

```
String locationString = *from DB*
String[] latLongStrings = locationString.split(",");
double lat = Double.parseDouble(latLongStrings[0]);
double long = Double.parseDouble(latLongStrings[1]);
```

However, you might want to adjust your DB schema to have two `REAL` columns instead of one `TEXT`

Comment: any pros and cons of having one text columns? other than having to cut the string? thanks!!

Comment: It's good form to use the right data types. It makes searching and managing the data easier.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to?  Trimming to an integer would lose a lot of accuracy-  you could be off by as much as .5 degrees, or 35 miles in either direction.